# Add multiple handlers on the same view?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-handler

I m trying to add more then one handler like this,

```
android:onClick="@{!data.navDrawer ? ()-> handler1.method1(data) : ()-> handler2.method2(data)}">
```

But above code is giving some syntax issue.

Where ***data.navDrawer*** is a ***boolean*** variable.

Please suggest is it possible? Or how to add 2 handlers on the same view.

Comment: What's the error and post code of linked files i.e layout and model class

Answer (score 0):

It can't be possible.

You can check internally by passing flag on handlers.